# Object Method Reference within Spring Integration Flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

A message is received on a channel, and is processed by a transformer. The output of the transformer is the following class, which is passed on to the next step in the flow:

```
public class DomainBean{

   public DomainBean process() {
      // code
      return this;
   }

}
```

Another bean has a `@Transformer` method which calls the `process` method on the bean above, as follows:

```
@Component
public class Handler {

    @Transformer
    public Object handle(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        DomainBean domainBean = (DomainBean) message;
        domainBean.process();
        return domainBean ;
    }

}
```

Within the IntegrationFlow, the `handle` method is invoked as follows:

```
.transform(handler)
```

Ideally I would like to do away with the `Handler` bean class, and call `domainBean.process()` using an object method reference, as follows:

```
.transform(DomainBean::process)
```

When I try that, or `.<DomainBean, DomainBean>transform(DomainBean::process)`
compiler complains that

```
Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. There is really this method in the `IntegrationFlowDefinition`:

```
 * Populate the {@link MessageTransformingHandler} instance for the provided {@link GenericTransformer}.
 * @param genericTransformer the {@link GenericTransformer} to populate.
 * @param <S> the source type - 'transform from'.
 * @param <T> the target type - 'transform to'.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @see MethodInvokingTransformer
 * @see LambdaMessageProcessor
 */
public <S, T> B transform(GenericTransformer<S, T> genericTransformer) {
```

Where that `GenericTransformer` really can be expressed as lambda or method reference and we have enough tests to confirm that. The code there looks like:

```
.transform("hello "::concat)
...
.<String, Integer>transform(Integer::parseInt)
...
.<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
...
.<MessagingException,  Message<?>>transform(MessagingException::getFailedMessage)
```

Maybe your problem that you need add exact generics agrs to the method? Therefore this:

```
.<DomainBean, DomainBean>transform(DomainBean::process)
```

However what I see that your `DomainBean.process()` is `void`. This signature doesn't fit the `transformer` purpose. Yes, you can do the same with a lambda what you have in the `Handler` or another solution is to use `.handle()`. This one really can call `void` method and, to be honest, that is exactly what fits to your logic - there is no any transformation logic so far.

However when service method is `void` there is no any continuation after this method call in the flow. Such a `.handle()` must be the last one-way endpoint in the flow definition. The `void` is equal to the [Outbound Channel Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-adapter-namespace-outbound).

Comment: Artem, thanks as always. Have updated the question with the error I get when trying to do as in your examples.

Comment: Yeah... I see now. Sorry. You have confused me with your wish to call that method via method reference. But since it's not a lambda for the context you would like to call, there is no way to handle it as method reference. Such a method must fit to the `GenericTransformer.transform()`  signature. Therefore no `DomainBean::process` for your there. You can workaround it only with the `.<DomainBean, DomainBean>transform(p -> { p.process(); return p; })`